# Creating news feed in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am creating a news feed functionality in cakephp, almost like facebook news feed.
posting topics and replying comments for the post.Replies for the post's is not apperaing properly.single reply is repeating for all the posts, there is some problem with looping or fetching the data.The replies should appear below each topic like below.

```
Topic1
  reply1fortopic1
  reply2fortopic1
Topic2
  reply1topic2
  reply2topic2
```

Here is my code

I am using two tables newsfeed, newsreplies.Relationship is mentioned in the models

Controller:

```
$newsfeed=array('group_id'=>$groupdata['Group']['id'],'status'=>'A');
$this->set('newsfeed',$this->paginate('NewsFeed',$newsfeed));
$newsdata=$this->paginate('NewsFeed',$newsfeed);


$newsreplies=$this->NewsFeed->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('NewsFeed.group_id'=>$group,'NewsFeed.status'=>'A')));
$this->set('newsreplies',$newsreplies);
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($newsdata as $newsdatas): ?>

           <div class="news_reply_display">
                    <?php echo $newsdatas['NewsFeed']['title']; ?>


            <?php foreach ($newsreplies as $newsreplly): ?>
                       <div class="news_reply_display">

                         <?php echo $newsreplly['NewsFeedComment']['comments']; ?>

                      </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Model:

NewsFeed.php

```
<?php
class NewsFeed extends AppModel {
var $name = 'NewsFeed';
var $useTable = 'news_feeds';
var $primaryKey = 'id';
var $hasMany = array(

'NewsFeedComment' => array(
'className' => 'NewsFeedComment',));
var $belongsTo = array(
'Group'=> array ('className' => 'Group','foreignKey' => 'group_id'),
'User'=> array ('className' => 'User','foreignKey' => 'user_id'));
}
?>
```

NewsFeedReply.php

```
<?php
class NewsFeedReply extends AppModel 
{
var $name = 'NewsFeedReply' ;
var $useTable = 'newsreplies';
var $primaryKey = 'id';
var $belongsTo = array(
'NewsFeed'=> array ('className' => 'NewsFeed','foreignKey' => 'news_feed_id'),
'User'=> array ('className' => 'User','foreignKey' => 'user_id'));
}
```

?>

Comment: in your view, add a `debug($newsreplies);` this will tell you the structure of your array so you know how to loop through it.

Comment: i have tried it, but the replies are not appearing below the corresponding topics.